# referencing on .click() only show destination for a short period

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to create a simple experiment using html/js.

My current code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>

  <script>
  var curTrial = 0;
  var stimuli = ['http://www.getty.edu/museum/media/images/web/enlarge/00066001.jpg',
  'http://www.getty.edu/museum/media/images/web/enlarge/00055301.jpg',
  'http://www.getty.edu/museum/media/images/web/enlarge/00066301.jpg']


/* Start the experiment */
function RunTrial() {
    $('#startTrial').hide();
    $('#box').hide();
    $('#box2').show();
    $('#trialNum').text(curTrial);
    $("#nexttrial").click(function(f) { BetweenTrial(); });
}

function StartExperiment() {
  startTime = new Date();
  $('#instructions').hide();
  $('#box').show();
  $('#box2').hide();
  $('#intrucBox').show();
  $("#next").click(function(f) { RunTrial(); });

//  $(document).bind("keypress.start", function(e) { RunTrial(); });
  }


function BetweenTrial(){
  $('#box2').hide();
  $('#box').show()
  $('#startTrial').show()
  $("#next").click(function(f) { RunTrial(); });
    } 


  </script>
</head>


<body>
<div id="instructions">
  <p> Visual perception of <strong>material properties. </strong></p> 
  <p style="text-align: center"><a href="javascript:StartExperiment()" id="startExperimentButton">
  StartExperiment</a></p>
  <div id="consentDiv">
  <p><u>Consent to Participate in Research:</u></p>    
  <p> <br> <br>By starting the experiment you consent to the EULA.</p>
  <p>By participating you are confirming that you are over 18 years of age
  and have normal or corrected-to-normal vision.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="box" style="text-align:center">
    <div id="startTrial">Press any key to start the next trial</div>
      <button id="next">Submit</button>

</div>


<div id="box2" style="text-align:center">   
    <div id="trialNum" style="text-align:left"></div>

    <img src="http://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/ad/web-large/DT212230.jpg" id="image"> 

    <form >
  Question 1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="answer"><br>
  Question 2:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="answer">
  <br><br>

  <button id="nexttrial">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>




</div>

</body>
<script>
    function StartScreen() { //Hide the parts of the website we don't need to show  yet
      $('#box').hide();
      $('#box2').hide();
      }
      StartScreen()
</script>

</html>
```

In `RunTrial()` I have

```
$("#nexttrial").click(function(f) { BetweenTrial(); });
```

When `#nexttrial` is clicked, it goes to `BetweenTrial()` as expected, but after about half a second, it disappears.  I do not understand why. How do I stop it from disappearing?

Comment: Its not an error. You submit a form. When the form is submitted, the page makes a reload with the parameters to `"https://tryit.w3schools.com/tryit_view.php?firstname=answer&lastname=answer"` That is why your page disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its because your button is submitting the form.  If a form only has 1 button it will assume that it is the submit even if you don't explicitly put type="submit".

to stop that just add f.preventDefault(); into your method so would be

```
$("#nexttrial").click(function(f) { f.preventDefault(); BetweenTrial(); });
```

hope that explains it

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your button(default is type `submit`) change it to:

```
<button id="nexttrial" type="button">Submit</button>
```

```html
<?php

?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>

  <script>
  var curTrial = 0;
  var stimuli = ['http://www.getty.edu/museum/media/images/web/enlarge/00066001.jpg',
  'http://www.getty.edu/museum/media/images/web/enlarge/00055301.jpg',
  'http://www.getty.edu/museum/media/images/web/enlarge/00066301.jpg']


/* Start the experiment */
function RunTrial() {
 $('#startTrial').hide();
    $('#box').hide();
    $('#box2').show();
    $('#trialNum').text(curTrial);
 $("#nexttrial").click(function(f) { BetweenTrial(); });
}

function StartExperiment() {
  startTime = new Date();
  $('#instructions').hide();
  $('#box').show();
  $('#box2').hide();
  $('#intrucBox').show();
  $("#next").click(function(f) { RunTrial(); });

//  $(document).bind("keypress.start", function(e) { RunTrial(); });
  }


function BetweenTrial(){
  $('#box2').hide();
  $('#box').show()
  $('#startTrial').show()
  $("#next").click(function(f) { RunTrial(); });
    } 
  
  
  </script>
</head>


<body>
<div id="instructions">
  <p> Visual perception of <strong>material properties. </strong></p> 
  <p style="text-align: center"><a href="javascript:StartExperiment()" id="startExperimentButton">
  StartExperiment</a></p>
  <div id="consentDiv">
  <p><u>Consent to Participate in Research:</u></p>    
  <p> <br> <br>By starting the experiment you consent to the EULA.</p>
  <p>By participating you are confirming that you are over 18 years of age
  and have normal or corrected-to-normal vision.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="box" style="text-align:center">
 <div id="startTrial">Press any key to start the next trial</div>
      <button id="next">Submit</button>

</div>


<div id="box2" style="text-align:center">   
 <div id="trialNum" style="text-align:left"></div>

 <img src="http://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/ad/web-large/DT212230.jpg" id="image"> 
    
    <form >
  Question 1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="answer"><br>
  Question 2:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="answer">
  <br><br>
  
  <button id="nexttrial" type="button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>


 

</div>

</body>
<script>
 function StartScreen() {
   $('#box').hide();
    $('#box2').hide();
      }
      StartScreen()
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: using type="button" should be the accepted answer imo

Comment: It works now. I was not aware of button defaults. Thank you.